# PDO::query() expects parameter 1 to be string error

Tags: php, sql

Im getting a parameter error but i dont really know how to fix it. What am i doing wrong?

```
function ToonProduct($productID) {
$query = "SELECT * 
            FROM stockitems s
            JOIN stockitemholdings sh ON s.StockItemID = sh.StockItemID
            WHERE s.StockItemID = :productid";
$query = connectionDB()->prepare ($query);
$query->bindParam(":productid", $productID, PDO::PARAM_INT);
$query->execute();
return connectionDB()->query( $query )->fetch(PDO::PARAM_STR);
```

This is the output im getting:

```
Warning: PDO::query() expects parameter 1 to be string, object given in C:\xampp\htdocs\wwi\includes\queries.php on line 47
```

This is line 47:

```
    return connectionDB()->query( $query )->fetch(PDO::PARAM_STR);
```

Comment: update your question and add  full error message text

Answer (score 1, accepted):

should be

```
$queryString = "SELECT * 
            FROM stockitems s
            JOIN stockitemholdings sh ON s.StockItemID = sh.StockItemID
            WHERE s.StockItemID = :productid";
$query = connectionDB()->prepare($queryString);
$query->bindParam(":productid", $productID, PDO::PARAM_INT);
$query->execute();
return $query->fetch(PDO::PARAM_STR);
```

If in trouble, refer to 
https://www.php.net/manual/en/pdo.prepare.php
and
https://www.php.net/manual/en/pdostatement.fetch.php
then doublecheck your code